# CTE error : " The multi-part identifier "cte.continent" could not be bound. "

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
 With cteCon  as
 (
   SELECT continent as continent , MAX(population) as population 
   FROM world
   GROUP BY continent 
   HAVING MAX(population) <= 25000000 
 ) 
SELECT name 
FROM world as x 
JOIN cteCon ON (x.continent = cte.continent)
```

Comment: which database are you using, ?

Comment: I do my homework on SQLzoo. I don't know what database they use on that site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
JOIN cteCon ON (x.continent = cte.continent)
```

with

```
JOIN cteCon ON (x.continent = cteCon.continent)
                              ^^^^^^
```

Comment: omg , i'm so noob... TKS !!!

Answer (score -1):

```
With cteCon  as
(
  SELECT continent as continent , MAX(population) as population 
  FROM world
  GROUP BY continent 
  HAVING MAX(population) <= 25000000 
) 
SELECT x.name 
FROM world as x 
JOIN cteCon as cte ON x.continent = cte.continent
```